# How to run two cmake commands from yocto recipe

Tags: linux, yocto

I am working on yocto, i have two cmake commands in recipe, inherit cmake will compile with EXTRA_OECMAKE to pass parameters.
I have one more command with different cmake commands with different paramets using the same source code.

```
How can i run the both cmake commands from a single recipe file.

Thank You,
```

[EDIT: adding comment in original question]

```
cmake -DEM_CONF=$CONFIG_PATH -DNOLEGACY=1 -DTESTING=1 -DTARGET=LINUX ..
```

I added

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DEM_CONF=$PWD/../git/test/integration/xm_config" 
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DNOLEGACY=1"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DTESTING=1"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DTARGET=LINUX"
```

now i want to do one more cmake command

```
cmake -DEM_LIB=$LIB_PATH -DEM_APPL=$APPL_PATH -DEM_CONF=$CONFIG_PATH -DTARGET=LINUX ../test/integration
```

first command will create static lib second will use it, If i mix first and second it is checking for static lib which is not created

Comment: Please add the commands you want to run, the answer is going to depend on what they are.

Comment: cmake -DEM_CONF=$CONFIG_PATH  -DNOLEGACY=1 -DTESTING=1 -DTARGET=LINUX ..                                 I added EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DEM_CONF=$PWD/../git/test/integration/xm_config"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DNOLEGACY=1"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DTESTING=1"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DTARGET=LINUX"        now i want to do one more  cmake command cmake -DEM_LIB=$LIB_PATH -DEM_APPL=$APPL_PATH  -DEM_CONF=$CONFIG_PATH  -DTARGET=LINUX ../test/integration   first command will create static lib second will use it, If i mix first and second it is checking for static lib which is not created

Comment: Do you have a link to your `CMakeLists.txt`? There's maybe a way to run the tests at the same time than generating library. Usually it is done this way.